# How to define a "formal offer" in remote working style?

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, spain

Nowadays, since pandemic broken, more and more companies take the remote working style. So some job position like programmers, companies would take the remote work style. So in this situation, I meet a new problem when I am seeking for a job. Which is, if a company said yes you are hired, then they will send a contract to my home, for example. Along with my work laptop.

So now the question is, how, or from when, I consider I received a formal offer? Because from the rule "We can not stop seeking a new job until we get an formal offer", but at the meanwhile, I don't want two different company send me their laptops and contracts at the same time and I have to reject one, that would ruin my reputation.

However, if I reject any other companies after one company send me "an offer" from their email, then it may not have "legal validity" (I am in Spain, but I don't know legal thing in this country). I can not fight for anything once they withdraw or regret for any reasons while I already reject other companies

Comment: What makes you think companies send you a laptop at the same time as an offer? Note that an offer isn't the same as your employment contract.

Comment: "I don't want two different company send me their laptops" Why would that happen? If you've chosen one company, put the other company on the backburner. Say you have to talk to you girlfriend, or come up with some excuse to delay giving an answer to that second company.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Spain, the actual employee contract is a large and detailed document, but it is the binding agreement, but it is not provided or signed until Day 1 of a job.  There are a number of implied rights you have under Spanish law (convenio colectivo) regardless of the contract.

When you make a verbal or email agreement to be employed, that is sufficiently binding to give notice at your previous job.  Do not agree to two offers of employment and you will not get two contracts at the same time.

There is such a thing as a “pre-contract” used to formalize an offer letter but this is generally only used with foreign nationals that need proof of a job to get a work visa.

Note there are new (Oct 2020) legal protections in Spain regarding remote work, see https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.natlawreview.com/article/spain-s-new-decree-remote-working%3famp

Comment: hello~~ so, once a company said he hire me, then I need to say, give me a email contain the offer, and once I receive the email, I can stop terminate all other process right?

Comment: Yes.  I mean, there is always some risk, as an offer is not fully binding and it could be rescinded at any time without recourse on your part, but this is a part of the process that is considered to be covered by professionalism.  In some countries you would "sign" an offer or get a contract ahead of time but the same structure that generates worker rights in Spain also makes it basically impossible to do anything other than the standard path, and day one contract is the standard path there.  So it's the default way it happens.

Comment: @Vincent, No, ask for a copy of the contract first (even if you're only supposed to sign it later). And if the contract mentions an employee handbook, ask for a copy of the handbook. You want to make sure that everything they've promised you during the interview is mentioned in the contract or in the handbook. Also, the contract should have a starting date. If the contract doesn't have a starting date, that's a red flag.